# Linq join 3 list <T>

Tags: c#, linq, list, join

I have three lists that I need to join together

```
class Person
{
    public int PersonID{ get; set; }
    public string FirstName{get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}

class Traffic
{
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
    public int PersonID;
    public int TrafficID;
}

class TrafficType
{
    public int TrafficID { get; set; }
    public string Description  { get; set; }
}

List<Person> Persons=GetPersons();

List<TrafficType> TrafficTypes=GetTrafficTypes();

List<Traffic> Traffics=GetTraffics();
```

I need an output like:

```
PersonID  FirstName  LastName      Date           Description 

 1001        David       ...      2011/07/19   sample description
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from person in Persons
from traffic in traffics
from trafficType in trafficTypes
where trafficType.TrafficID = traffic.TrafficID 
where traffic.PersonID = person.PersonID
select new 
{
    PersonID = person.PersonID,
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Persons.Join(
    Traffics,
    person => person.PersonID,
    trafic => trafic.PersonID,
    (person, trafic) => new
    {
        PersonId = person.PersonID,
        FirstName = person.FirstName,
        LastName = person.LastName,
        Date = trafic.Date,
        TraficId = trafic.TrafficID
    }).Join(
        TrafficTypes,
        a => a.TraficId,
        traficType => traficType.TrafficID,
        (a, traficType) => new
        {
            PersonId = a.PersonId,
            FirstName = a.FirstName,
            LastName = a.LastName,
            Date = a.Date,
            Description = traficType.Description
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete code sample with Linq query expression code that should get exactly what you're looking for:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Traffic
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int TrafficId { get; set; }
}

class TrafficType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var persons = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person()
            {
                Id = 1001,
                FirstName = "David",
                LastName = "Jones",
            },
        };
        var trafficTypes = new List<TrafficType>()
        {
            new TrafficType()
            {
                Id = 456,
                Description = "sample description",
            },
        };
        var traffics = new List<Traffic>()
        {
            new Traffic()
            {
                PersonId = 1001,
                TrafficId = 456,
                Date = DateTime.Now,
            },
        };

        var joinedData = from p in persons
                         from t in traffics
                         from tt in trafficTypes
                         where p.Id == t.PersonId
                            && tt.Id == t.TrafficId
                         select new
                         {
                             PersonId = p.Id,
                             FirstName = p.FirstName,
                             LastName = p.LastName,
                             // Remove time component, if present
                             Date = t.Date.Date,
                             Description = tt.Description,
                         };

        foreach (var item in joinedData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}"
                , item.PersonId
                , item.FirstName
                , item.LastName
                , item.Date.ToShortDateString() // Don't print the time
                , item.Description
                );
        }
    }
}
```

The program output is:

```
1001    David   Jones   7/19/2011       sample description
```

Comment: Also note that `ID` is an abbreviation, not an acronym, so should be written: `Id` (camel case).

Answer (score 0):

You can put them all in a class e.g. (Problem), then use a method for your output.

```
class Problem
{
   public Problem()
   {

   }

   public void Show()
   {
         // implement your output here
   }

}
```

Or, if you are using Windows Forms app and interisting in Tables, you can use DataGridView control. For more information about it, visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx

Or, use DataGrid: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/usingdatagrid.aspx